# Dismiss popup when click on a Image

Tags: android, popup

```
public void onListItemClick(ListView parent, View v, int position, long id) 
  {         
      super.onListItemClick(parent, v, position, id);



  LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)
       this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
 final PopupWindow pw = new PopupWindow(
       inflater.inflate(R.layout.offer_popup, null, false), 
       500, 
       600, 
       true);

 pw.showAtLocation(this.findViewById(android.R.id.list), Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);    

ImageView closeimage=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
closeimage.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    pw.dismiss();
    }
});
```

offer_popup.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"
android:orientation="vertical" android:weightSum="1">
 <RelativeLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:id="@+id/relativeLayout_popup"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="0.65">
    <ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:src="@drawable/node_largeview_black" 
     android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
     android:id="@+id/imageView1" 
     android:layout_alignParentTop="true" 
     android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
      android:layout_marginTop="61dp"></ImageView>
    <ImageView android:id="@+id/imageView2" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:src="@drawable/close_button" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageView1"
     android:layout_alignRight="@+id/imageView1"></ImageView>
  </RelativeLayout>
 </LinearLayout>
```

i have a listview, and if I clicked on one of item row, a popup would created, using offer_popup.xml, inside this xml, there's a imageView2 id which is a close image, and click on that, the popup would dismissed.

However, the program crashed closeimage=null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
View popView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.offer_popup, null, false);
final PopupWindow pw = new PopupWindow(popView
       , 
       500, 
       600, 
       true);
ImageView closeimage=(ImageView) popView.findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
```

change your code, to the above, you need to give the parent reference for the image to find it, if it's not part of main layout.

Comment: OK, now it didn't crash however, I click on closeimage, images of the popup didn't get closed.

Answer (score 1):

Make a `View` of `offer_popup` xml file and using that view find ImageView..

```
View popViewWindow = inflater.inflate(R.layout.offer_popup, null, false);  
ImageView closeimage=(ImageView)popViewWindow.findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
```

Comment: OK, now it didn't crash however, I click on closeimage, images of the popup didn't get closed.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think your closeimage is part of your activity's view hierarchy.  Try saving a reference to the offer_popup view and getting the closeimage from there:

```
View popupView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.offer_popup, null, false);
final PopupWindow pw = new PopupWindow(
   popupView, 
   500, 
   600, 
   true);
ImageView closeimage=(ImageView) popupView.findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
//...
```

Comment: OK, now it didn't crash however, I click on closeimage, images of the popup didn't get closed.

Comment: I'd try putting some log messages in or tracing with the debugger to see if your onclick listener is being called.  If not, try changing the src of closeimage and make sure it is the one you think it is and that you're clicking the right place. Check if pw is pointing at the popup, and not null or something unexpected.  Watch logcat when trying to close the popup, and see if any exceptions are thrown.  These are just the first ideas that come to mind -- your guess is probably as good as mine.  Good luck!